# Is Canvas compatible in Android 4.2 with Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2, html5-canvas

I'm developing a mobile app with Sencha Touch 2. I need use Canvas, but in Android 4.2 don't work correct. Is Canvas compatible in Android 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Canvas is  compatible in Android 4.2 directly

There might be an error in your code.

Post your error log /code

Read this you"ll get your answer

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

you have two canvas.addEventListeners at   touchstart and touchend both are called so you get 2 canvases drawn

Comment: I debug the App with PhoneGap Debug and dont't show me any errors or warning. The problem is that the App in Android devices draws twice the Canvas element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691048/dont-draw-correctly-canvas-in-device-android-4-2-2-with-sencha

Comment: you are calling the function(e) twice so the canvas gets created twice

Comment: touchstart and touchend both are created

Comment: This isn't the problem. The problem is that draw the image twice. In iOs devices and browse works correct, but in Android 4.x devices doesn't work correct.